# Knockout: accessing viewmodel instance in HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, viewmodel, knockout.js, data-binding

I am having a viewmodel and an associated template as below.

```
var AilmentItem = function () {
    this.SelectedAilment = ko.observable();
}

function AilmentsViewModel() {
    this.Ailments = ko.observableArray([new AilmentItem()]);
    this.AilmentsType = ko.observableArray([{ Name: 'Diabetes' }, { Name: 'Arthritis' }, { Name: 'High BP'}]);
}
```

HTML script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var AilmentsVM = new AilmentsViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(AilmentsVM, $('#Ailments')[0]);
    });
</script>
<div id="Ailments">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody data-bind='template: { name: "ailmentRowTemplate", foreach: Ailments }'>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="ailmentRowTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td><select data-bind="options: AilmentsVM.AilmentsType(),  optionsText: 'Name', value: SelectedAilment"></select></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

In the HTML template I need to bind AilmentsType to one of the columns as drop down. Can someone guide me how to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AilmentsVM` does not have global scope, because it is being created in your jQuery ready block, so you can't access it directly in a data-bind.

If you are using 1.3 beta, then you can use either the `$root` or `$parent` special variables that Knockout provides.  In this case, they would be the same, as you are only one level in from the top-level scope.  So, just do: `$root.AilmentsType`.

If you are using an earlier version, then you can use the `templateOptions` functionality to pass options to a jQuery template.  It would look like this:

```
<tbody data-bind='template: { name: "ailmentRowTemplate", foreach: Ailments, templateOptions: { types: AilmentsType } }'>
</tbody>
```

Then, access it like:

```
<select data-bind="options: $item.types,  optionsText: 'Name', value: SelectedAilment"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks RP Niemeyer. I have switched to 1.3 and it is simplifying things.